# need help in understanding the following for loop

Tags: linear-regression

i m new to coding and am trying to understand the following lines of python codes, especially the for loop. Can someone help me in understanding it in detail?

```py
regression_model = LinearRegression()
regression_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

for idx, col_name in enumerate(X_train.columns):
    print("The coefficient for {} is {}".format(col_name, regression_model.coef_[0][idx]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'll order it by lines:

1: Set regression_model as an instance of a linear regression model.

2: Fitting a linear regression model on your training dataset.

3:

4: Iterate for each column in your X dataset (features):

5: Print the coefficient of --COLUMN NAME--

The number of lines in your output should be equal to the number of columns in your X_train dataset.

Every column name will be printed with its coefficient (the impact of that specific feature on the dependent variable).

I don't know what did you write earlier in that code, but this code will most likely not be functioning.